# tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable takes hours to complete when big data set involves

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, sql-server-2012, tdd, tsqlt

```
EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'expected', 'actual';
```

I am comparing expected vs actual tables. This table has 100k plus records and if 80k records match 20k records don't match then tsqlt will paint like below each failed row and it takes hours of time to complete. How can avoid tsqlt displaying the unmatched records in the output?

These tables would result in the following failure message:

```
failed: unexpected/missing resultset rows!
|_m_|col1|col2|col3|
+---+----+----+----+
|<  |2   |B   |b   |
|<  |3   |C   |c   |
|=  |1   |A   |a   |
|>  |3   |X   |c   |
```

Comment: 100K rows seems a bit excessive for a unit test. Just sayin.

Comment: What about if you add an explicit message parameter `, @FailMsg = 'rows failed'` see docs https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/assertions/assertequalstable/

Comment: @Charlieface - looks like that just replaces the `‘unexpected/missing resultset rows!’.` part of the output as that is the parameter default

Comment: Yes, @Charlieface it is just replace the text and not stopping tsqlt to stop painting the failed records for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100,000 rows is far in excess of what is reasonably required for a unit test.

You should be able to test all scenarios with considerably fewer rows than that.

But if `tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable` doesn't meet your needs as it prints out potentially huge strings you can just do your own checks and assertions - e.g. as below (assumes `Actual` and `Expected` have the same column schema definitions).

```
DECLARE @expectedRows INT,
        @actualRows   INT,
        @expectedChk  INT,
        @actualChk    INT;

SELECT @expectedRows = COUNT(*),
       @expectedChk = CHECKSUM_AGG(binary_checksum(*))
FROM   Expected

SELECT @actualRows = COUNT(*),
       @actualChk = CHECKSUM_AGG(binary_checksum(*))
FROM   Actual

EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals
  @expectedRows,
  @actualRows,
  'Mismatched rowcount between expected and actual'

EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals
  @expectedChk,
  @actualChk,
  'Mismatched checksum between expected and actual'

--Row count the same and checksum the same. Do more rigorous check.
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   (SELECT 1 AS [️], *
                  FROM   Expected) E
                 FULL JOIN (SELECT 1 AS [️], *
                            FROM   Actual) A
                        ON EXISTS(SELECT A.*
                                  INTERSECT
                                  SELECT E.*)
          WHERE  A.[️] IS NULL
                  OR E.[️] IS NULL)
  EXEC tSQLt.Fail
    'Mismatched row content between expected and actual';
```

Comment: Always annoys me that there is no `XOR JOIN`...